# Need to get one to many in PIVOT condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have sample data

```
Empid   Emp_Name    Dept    Part
1        Mohan     English  Part-1
1        Mohan     English  Part-2
1        Mohan     Maths    part-1
1        Mohan     Maths    part-2
2        Madhu     English  Part-1
2        Madhu     English  Part-2
2        Madhu     Maths    Part-1
2        Madhu     Maths    Part-2
```

Using Pivot I'm getting like this

```
Select Empid,Emp_Name,[maths],[english] from (
Select Empid,Emp_Name,Dept,part from  @tbl)T
PIVOT (MAX(part) FOR dept IN ( [maths],[english]))PVT
```

Result :

```
 Empid    Emp_Name      maths   english
    2        Madhu      Part-2  Part-2
    1        Mohan      part-2  Part-2
```

How can I get output like this :

```
Empid   Emp_Name    maths   english
2        Madhu    Part-2    Part-2
2        Madhu    Part-1    Part-1
1        Mohan    part-2    Part-2
1        Mohan    part-1    Part-1
```

can you please suggest on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need groping on parts, so you can do conditional aggregation :

```
select empid, emp_name, 
       max(case when dept = 'maths' then part end) as maths,
       max(case when dept = 'english' then part end) as english
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by empid, emp_name, dept order by part) as seq
      from @tbl t
     ) t
group by empid, emp_name, seq
order by empid desc, maths desc, english desc;
```

If you want to go with `pivot` version, then use `row_number()` inside `inner select` statement to make it group.